# How I can get medial player Duration and stop Chronometer?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-mediaplayer, avaudioplayer, chronometer

I am making a  android simple media player for playing a audio files and facing a problem with it.

I want to stop Chronometer and media player

**When the current Duration of playing file  == total duration of file..?**

Here is my demo code.

```
   private void playAudio() {
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(outputFile);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
            mChronometer.start();
            mediaPlayer.start();
            long totalDuration = mediaPlayer.getDuration();

            Log.i("MediaPlayer", String.valueOf(totalDuration));
        }
```

here is another code added from answer .
i add the listrner 
**mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(CompletionListener);**

```
 MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener CompletionListener = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

            long totalDuration = mp.getDuration();


        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `onCompletionListener` to check when media player has reached end of the media file.

```
    mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
         // do your task
    }
});
```

For further reference see this link

[Media Player](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener.html)

Comment: can you explain more  ...?

what i can  do  onCompletion  according to my example ...?

Comment: well on `completionListener` method will be called current Duration of playing file == total duration of file. So in this method you can write the code that you want to do on that condition

Comment: i don't getting your point bro   

see i update  my code  write some code example   if you can

Comment: Yup  sry sry   i got

Comment: you don't need to get duration in onCompletion method. You just have to stop your chronometer in it